# ionic 3 pull to refresh causing complete ion-content scroll in ios

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I had segment-buttons on top and ion-list down to it. I had ion-refresher at top of the list . When i continuously pull ion-refresher, Iam getting over-scroll effect in ios i.e., the segment buttons are getting pulled along with the list. I tried options no-bounce , has-bouncing="false", over-scroll="false" and what all I found in google, but nothing seems to work in ios.

Thanks in advance.